# Java reading a file different methods

Tags: java, file-io

It seems that there are many, many ways to read text files in Java (`BufferedReader`, `DataInputStream` etc.) My personal favorite is `Scanner` with a `File` in the constructor (it's just simpler, works with mathy data processing better, and has familiar syntax).

Boris the Spider also mentioned `Channel` and `RandomAccessFile`.

Can someone explain the pros and cons of each of these methods? To be specific, when would I want to use each?

(edit) I think I should be specific and add that I have a strong preference for the `Scanner` method. So the real question is, when *wouldn't* I want to use it?

Comment: Don't forget `Channel` and `RandomAccessFile` and their ilk... All these methods are _different_. Some read binary streams. Some character streams. Some tokenise input. There aren't really comparable - they have different use scenarios.

Comment: " they have different use scenarios. " Yeah. That's why I wanted to ask.

Comment: my "weapon of choice" is the `LineNumberReader`. Ideal for line-by-line reading and parsing of human-readable text files like csv.

Comment: I really found `Scanner` useful for reading a one-dimensional white-space delimited ascii data file.

Comment: `Scanner` isn't really comparable to the others. The other techniques mentioned here just do the I/O. `Scanner` does scanning and format conversion.

Comment: @EJP I mean that `Scanner` abstracts I/O away from the user and serves, in my experience, in most cases (who really wants to parse manually?). The real question is whether a lower- or higher-level API is advantageous.

Comment: If that's the real question, you haven't stated it in your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lets start at the beginning. The question is what do you want to do?

It's important to understand what a file actually is. A file is a collection of bytes on a disc, these bytes are your data. There are various levels of abstraction above that that Java provides:

1. `File(Input|Output)Stream` - read these bytes as a stream of `byte`.
2. `File(Reader|Writer)` - read from a stream of bytes as a stream of `char`.
3. `Scanner` - read from a stream of `char` and tokenise it.
4. `RandomAccessFile` - read these bytes as a searchable `byte[]`.
5. `FileChannel` - read these bytes in a safe multithreaded way.

On top of each of those there are the [Decorators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), for example you can add buffering with `BufferedXXX`. You could add linebreak awareness to a `FileWriter` with `PrintWriter`. You could turn an `InputStream` into a `Reader` with an `InputStreamReader` (currently the only way to specify character encoding for a `Reader`).

So - *when wouldn't I want to use it [a `Scanner`]?*.

You would not use a `Scanner` if you wanted to, (these are some examples):

1. Read in data as `byte`s
2. Read in a serialized Java object
3. Copy `byte`s from one file to another, maybe with some filtering.

It is also worth nothing that the `Scanner(File file)` constructor takes the `File` and opens a `FileInputStream` with the **platform default encoding** - this is almost always a **bad** idea. It is generally recognised that you should specify the encoding explicitly to avoid nasty encoding based bugs. Further the stream isn't buffered.

So you may be better off with

```
try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream())), "UTF-8") {
    //do stuff
}
```

Ugly, I know.

It's worth noting that Java 7 Provides a further layer of abstraction to remove the need to loop over files - these are in the [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class:

```
byte[] Files.readAllBytes(Path path)
List<String> Files.readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs)
```

Both these methods read the entire file into memory, which might not be appropriate. In Java 8 this is further improved by adding support for the new `Stream` API:

```
Stream<String> Files.lines(Path path, Charset cs)
Stream<Path> Files.list(Path dir)
```

For example to get a [Stream](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of words from a `Path` you can do:

```
    final Stream<String> words = Files.lines(Paths.get("myFile.txt")).
            flatMap((in) -> Arrays.stream(in.split("\\b")));
```

Comment: Nice corollary. Especially the mention of Java 8 is worth wile, as the question addresses future code design.

Comment: Did you mean to say "file" instead of "`File`"? ;)

Answer (score 3):

`SCANNER:`

can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions.
A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types.more can be read at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

`DATA INPUT STREAM:`

Lets an application read primitive Java data types from an underlying input stream in a machine-independent way. An application uses a data output stream to write data that can later be read by a data input stream.DataInputStream is not necessarily safe for multithreaded access. Thread safety is optional and is the responsibility of users of methods in this class. More can be read at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html

`BufferedReader:`

Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.The buffer size may be specified, or the default size may be used. The default is large enough for most purposes.In general, each read request made of a Reader causes a corresponding read request to be made of the underlying character or byte stream. It is therefore advisable to wrap a BufferedReader around any Reader whose read() operations may be costly, such as FileReaders and InputStreamReaders. For example,

```
BufferedReader in   = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));
```

will buffer the input from the specified file. Without buffering, each invocation of read() or readLine() could cause bytes to be read from the file, converted into characters, and then returned, which can be very inefficient.Programs that use DataInputStreams for textual input can be localized by replacing each DataInputStream with an appropriate BufferedReader.More detail are at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This approach is outdated.  As Boris points out in his comment.  I will leave it here for history, but you should use methods available in JDK.

It depends on what kind of operation you are doing and the size of the file you are reading.

In most of the cases, I recommend using [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) for small files.

```
byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("myfile"));
```

You can read it as string or character array...

Now, you are handing big files, or changing parts of a file directly on the filesystem, then the best it to use a RandomAccessFile and potentially even a FileChannel to do "nio" style.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the other methods and explain why you prefer this one?

Comment: This is very outdated - the JDK has had these methods since Java 7 using the nio API. Why people insist on still using the `File` based API and then installing 3rd party libraries is completely beyond me. But recommending others to take up this methodology is just not good.

Comment: Actually, I think `Scanner` could do this, albeit slightly more expensively. But file I/O performance usually doesn't matter that much, and when it does, the bottleneck is usually the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Using BufferedReader

```
BufferedReader reader;
char[] buffer = new char[10];
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FILE_PATH"));
//or
    reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Path.get("FILE_PATH"));
    while (reader.read(buffer) != -1) {
            System.out.print(new String(buffer));
            buffer = new char[10];
    }
//or
    while (buffReader.ready()) {
            System.out.println(
                buffReader.readLine());
        }
    reader.close();
```

Using FileInputStream-Read Binary Files to Bytes

```
FileInputStream fis;
byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
    fis = new FileInputStream("FILE_PATH");
//or
    fis=Files.newInoutSream(Paths.get("FILE_PATH"))
    while (fis.read(buffer) != -1) {
        System.out.print(new String(buffer));
        buffer = new byte[10];
    }
    fis.close();
```

Using Files– Read Small File to List of Strings

```
List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("FILE_PATH"));
for (String line : allLines) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Using Scanner – Read Text File as Iterator

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("FILE_PATH"));
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
scanner.close();
```

Using RandomAccessFile-Reading Files in Read-Only Mode

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("FILE_PATH", "r");
String str;
while ((str = file.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
file.close();
```

Using Files.lines-Reading lines as stream

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("FILE_PATH") .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Using FileChannel-for increasing performance by using off-heap memory furthermore using MappedByteBuffer

```
FileInputStream i = new FileInputStream(("FILE_PATH");
        ReadableByteChannel r = i.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16 * 1024);
        while (r.read(buffer) != -1) {
            buffer.flip();
            while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                    System.out.print((char) buffer.get());
            }
            buffer.clear();
        }
```