# Java NIO, FileLocks, and Readers

Tags: java, file-io, nio

I want to read a text file but also acquire a file lock on the file.

It seems the only way to get a file lock is by calling a method on the file channel.

Now, I've seen `BufferedReader`, `FileReader`, and `RandomAccessFile` and only `RandomAccessFile` has a `.getChannel()`

I was originally using that but I was told somewhere else I should try using the NIO stuff (and that `RandomAccessFile` wasn't **NIO**).

So I switched to just using FileChannel and reading bytes in **manually** and **this isn't working.**

Is using `BufferedReader`, `FileReader`, and `RandomAccessFile` still using the **NIO** things? Is there any way to acquire a lock on `BufferedReader` and `FileReader`?

(And if it's not too much to ask, how does a Scanner fit in with these three?
There seems like there's just so many ways to read a file and I'm not comprehending the differences)

Comment: I wrote [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21824010/2071828) covering some (but not all) of these topics a little while ago. As far as file locking goes - this is tricky extra-JVM as non-Windows OSes don't support it.

Comment: File locking is advisory and _not_ compulsory (or maybe on Windows it can be, as @BoristheSpider suggests... I don't do Windows so I don't know); if you don't cooperate using the same locking mechanisms exactly, you won't get locked, NIO or not.

Comment: @fge I don't do Windows either but I am led to believe by the Windows folks that there is a mandatory locking mechanism in place - [Wikipedia supports that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Microsoft_Windows) (although that is hardly authoritative).

Comment: The topic you linked was tremendously helpful. Read through the whole thing and has cleared up most of my confusion.

Comment: Oh, wait, I think I found a way. Using a FileInputStream (Which reads in bytes), you can use .getChannel() on that to get the channel and then get a lock. Then you can construct an InputStreamReader in order to read the FileInputStream as characters.

Comment: I've seen no evidence that the back end of anything in java.io or java.net has been replaced by java.nio.

Comment: Did a bit more research and you're right. There's nothing I've found that actually says anything to the sort. All the stuff I'd seen before hadn't really said one way or the other so I just made an assumption. Now I wonder why the one guy was telling me to use NIO, because I really didn't need to use such low level file channels at all :/