# Efficient Way to Read a File Java

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

What is the most efficient way to read input from a file ?

I have a very very large file which contains a list of words separated by a newline

e.g

```
computer
science 
is 
fun
really
```

I was thinking about using a `BufferedReader` object however I was confused by this line in the documentation.

> "In general, each read request made of a Reader causes a corresponding read request to be made of the underlying character or byte stream. It is therefore advisable to wrap a BufferedReader around any Reader whose read() operations may be costly, such as FileReaders and InputStreamReaders. For example,
>
> ```
> BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));
> ```
>
> will buffer the input from the specified file. Without buffering, each invocation of read() or readLine() could cause bytes to be read from the file, converted into characters, and then returned, which can be very inefficient. " <

Can some please explain this to me?
On second read I starting to believe the `BufferedReader` is my best bet. Is there a better way?

Comment: That advice is nothing to do with the size of the file.

Comment: Please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21824010/2071828) I wrote to another question. You have misunderstood what a `BufferedReader` is. It is a [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), it doesn't actually _read_ anything.

Comment: Explain *what* about it? What do you not understand?

Answer (score 8):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817816/java-reading-a-file-different-methods) may help.

BufferedReader is a good choice, letting you turn a BufferedReader into a java.util.Stream in Java 8.

Parsing a large CSV file for instance with `java.util.stream` package:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("persons.csv"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

List<Person> persons = br.lines()
    .substream(1)
    .map(mapToPerson)
    .filter(person -> person.getAge() > 17)
    .limit(50)
    .collect(toList());
```

Unlike Collections which are in-memory data structures which hold elements within it , Streams allow parallel processing and behave like fixed data structures which computes the elements on-demand basis. 
Moreover, Streams also support Pipelining and Internal Iterations.

Comment: +1 Streams are much cooler, and not too much slower than just using a loop.

Comment: Thank you @ludo_rj. Quick question. What is is the advantages or wrapping a BufferedReader with a InputStreamReader vs a FileReader ?

Comment: FileReader prevents from setting an encoding (ie platform dependent). InputStream is not limited to files, it allows to handle various sources like network connections and many others...

Comment: The method substream(int) is undefined for the type Stream<String>, is it deprecated ?

Comment: This method was renamed from substream to skip.