# Remove accents from string: java Normalizer

Tags: java, csv, diacritics, non-ascii-characters

I have a CSV file containing some French words (with accents). I want to read this file using Java and convert the accented letters to non-accented letters. For example, é should be read as e. I have tried the following:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
String[] line;
while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
      line[0] = Normalizer.normalize(line[0], Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                        .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9:_']", "_");
      System.out.println("LINE[0]: "+line[0]);
}
```

If suppose, the file contains the line "Arts_et_Métiers", the output is "Arts_et_MAtiers" where the accented letter is replaced by 'A' and not 'e'. Is there something that I am doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's reading the file correctly to start with? You're using `FileReader`, which always uses the platform-default encoding - not generally a good idea.

Comment: The code is working for me with that input text. It's probably an encoding problem.

Comment: Further to the above comments re encoding, see [my answer on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21824010/2071828). And **always make sure to close your resources** - in this case `try-with-resources` would be the correct approach.

Comment: you also could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27789934/3998458)

Comment: @JonSkeet: FileReader could be a possible problem! Will check that and let you know! :)

Comment: @BoristheSpider: This code snippet is just a small part. The complete code ensures that all the resources are closed after use.

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz: I tried using the StringUtils.stripAccents() from Apache Commons but it doesn't help!

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you suggest some encoding scheme that I should use? The original file is in .xlsx format, and I am reading it using a CSVReader.

Comment: @Neha: I would suggest using something which is designed to read Excel files... they're generally not just CSV files.

Comment: Maybe do `.replace("œ", "oe")` too. Form.NFKD unfortunately does not do that I think.

Comment: Maybe the .xlsx in reality is a text file (as CSVReader reads it), just renamed to let it be opened by Excel. Open it with a programmers editor like Notepad++ or JEdit and you can find out its encoding. "Cp1252" or "UTF-8" probably.

Comment: So sorry, the file is a CSV file, and not .xlsx file